# Looking for store names, admin and "distro" in Mage_Core_Model_App

Tags: magento-1.7, php, custom

So, my first problem was involving putting a custom price on a product. Upon many searches, I've discovered that Ben Gribaudo has a great tutorial that I'm looking for in order to programmatically change a price when entering an object into the store.  The only thing that ***I*** am not understanding is understanding where to get the ***_STORE_ID*** for the "Admin" and "Distro" that he speaks of.  Please take a look at the following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load($productId);
$product->setSpecialPrice($price);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product->save();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::DISTRO_STORE_ID);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $quantity));
$cart->save();
```

For reference, here is the link to explain what he's talking about: http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2011/07/29/1514/programmatically-setting-m-items-price-when-adding-to-cart

So, my **BIG QUESTION** is this: How does one ascertain the **ADMIN_STORE_ID** and **DISTRO_STORE_ID** to be plugged into the 4th and 6th lines of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem more generally, instead of setting the store context back to DISTRO_STORE_ID, we should instead remember the current context *before* we switch to admin. Basically the ADMIN part stays the same.

```
// Save the current store context before switching to admin:
$savedCurrentStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

// Switch to admin
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
// Do admin stuff ...

// ... after we finish admin stuff, restore store context:
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($savedCurrentStoreId);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've updated my article to reflect the suggestion it contains!